# Is this the right way to store simple social media stats

Tags: database-design, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to track really simple social media stats for some companies. At this stage I'm largely storing just their total audience size on different social media platforms.

Is this structure the best way to do this or is there a more efficient/better way?

Stores the base brand information

```
Schema::create('brands', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('slug')->nullable();
            $table->string('url')->unique();
            $table->integer('total_audience')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

Stores information about specific instances of accounts on social networks

```
Schema::create('brandAccounts', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('brand_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands');
            $table->enum('network', array('facebook', 'twitter', 'instagram','youtube'));
            $table->string('network_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

Stores individual data points for specific social media accounts.

```
    Schema::create('brandAccountLogs', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('brand_account_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('brand_account_id')->references('id')->on('brandAccounts');
        $table->integer('log')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

I should probably put indexes on the foreign keys too.

Comment: More indexes should also be considered based on the type of queries you want to run on this data. If for example you want to retrieve a timeline of how the number of followers of a brand are behaving over time, then an index on brandAccountLogs: (brand_account_id, timestamp_created) is needed.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think to put an index on the timestamps